# Selecting Item with Bootstrap Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to write javascript code for a Bootstrap Dropdown box, but I don't know how to refer to an item in the dropdown. There is no ID or Class that I can refer to when I'm writing things like if statements like for instance if (item1 is selected or is true) {"something happens"}. How can I refer to item1 or item2 or item3?

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li role="presentation" class="item1"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">item1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="item2"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">item2</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="item3"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">item3</a></li>

  </ul>

    $('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(){
       if($('.dropdown-menu li.item1')){
            $('item1Box').fadeTo(200, 0);
           }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize it a bit to your requirement. So, For example you can add custom class on the selected values during the change event of dropdown and set it as selected.

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(){
    //Remove previously selected 
    $('.dropdown-menu li').removeClass("selectedValue");
    //Add selected flag to current element
    $(this).addClass("selectedValue");
});
```

And you can check for the selected value in you any case using ,

```
$('.dropdown-menu li.selectedValue');
```

Or, Furthermore you can add your own class and id as required to the Bootstrap dropdown list as required.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li role="presentation" class="first-value"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">item1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="second-value"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">item2</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="third-value"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">item3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Based on sort of what you said I rewrote. See code at top of page. When item1 is selected the dropbox I want to appear, which currently has an opacity:0 should fade into visible, but nothing appears. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do switch and case (li.value=item1) ......
and maybe you should put value="item1" in li element -or rather get rid of those links and do it via Javascript  /jquery   I have something like that   `switch(li.value){ (item1) : $("#dropdown-menu").attr("action", page1.html); $("#dropdown-menu").submit(); break; (item2) : .....    }`  and I think those li are "indexed" or server knows taht item1 is 1st

... and triger that switch on form = dropdown submit

Answer (score 0):

some thing like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/he2d1mmt/

```
  <div class="dropdown">
        <button id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown trigger
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu pres" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
          <li role="presentation" class="item1"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#)">item1</a></li>
          <li role="presentation" class="item2"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">item2</a></li>
          <li role="presentation" class="item3"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">item3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".pres").children().click(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo(200, 0);
  });
});
</script>
```